# sending Json data to server using AT commands

Tags: at-command, gprs, sim900

I am having a website which accepts json data with post method.It works fine when i try sending the request from POSTMAN rest client.
When i am trying to the same using AT commands its failing.

[image]

This is the AT sequence i tried

```
AT
AT+CREG? 
AT+CGATT?
AT+CIPSHUT
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIPMUX=0 
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com"
AT+CSTT="airtelgprs.com"
AT+CIICR
AT+CIFSR
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIPSTART= "TCP","obdsam.herokuapp.com","80"
AT+CIPSEND
>
POST /newtasks HTTP/1.1 (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
HOST: obdsam.herokuapp.com" (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
Accept: application/json (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
Content-Type: application/json (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
{"RPM":"41","ECT":"20"} (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
(ctrl+j)(ctrl+z)
```

What could be the issue?

This is the reply from serial terminal

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue. After AT+CIPSEND the message must be like this
>

```
POST /newtasks HTTP/1.1 (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
HOST: obdsam.herokuapp.com (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
Accept: application/json (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
Content-Type: application/json(Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
Content-Length: 23 (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J) (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
{"RPM":"55","ECT":"55"} (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)(ctrl+j)(ctrl+z)
```

Comment: what is Ctrl+M Ctrl+J etc? Do I need it?

Comment: @Amir its CR and LF, you need to send that, see asciitable for combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have observed common mistakes in omitting `(ctrl+m)(ctrl+j)` combinations. In the above post , the first five lines belongs to `HTTP header` and the sixth line is the `HTTP body`. Note that the fifth line should end with two sets of `carriage return` and `line feed` to indicate end of `HTTP header`.

Also, wait until `CIPSTART` returns `CONNECT OK`, and wait until `> appears after`CIPSEND`.

If you are `GET/POST`-ing a page with dynamic IP, your code should be quick enough to `fetch/post` the page before the IP changes.

Have a nice day....